# Steps in Resolving the Integral: $\int\frac{1}{x^3}e^\frac{1}{x}dx$

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts

Could anyone assist me in a step by step solution to solving the following integral?

$$ \int\frac{1}{x^3}e^\frac{1}{x}\,dx $$

I have tried using both sides in integration by parts, but can't seem to come to a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $u = \frac{1}{x}, du = -\frac{1}{x^{2}}$. Therefore: $ \large\int\frac{1}{x^3}e^\frac{1}{x}dx = \int -ue^{u}du$. Now use parts.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int  \frac { 1 }{ x^{ 3 } } e^{ \frac { 1 }{ x }  }dx=-\int  \frac { 1 }{ x } e^{ \frac { 1 }{ x }  }d\left( \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right) \\$$

then set $$ \frac { 1 }{ x } =t$$
so that  to solve $$-\int { t{ e }^{ t }dt } $$ by parts

Comment: What happened to the $3$ in $\large\frac{1}{x^3}$?

Comment: it is under differention because ,$\\ d\left( \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right) =-\frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } } $